# Generate bivariate random numbers from a joint probability distribution in Python

Tags: probability, random, python, bivariate-distributions

I have two distributions over two parameters h and t. h is Weibull distributed while t is conditioned on h and it is log-normal distributed:

```
f_H = np.exp(-(h / alpha) ** beta) * (beta / alpha) * (h / alpha) ** (beta - 1)
f_TIH = np.exp(-(np.log(t) - mu_h) ** 2.0 / (2.0 * sigma_h ** 2)) / (t * sigma_h * np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi))
```

where:

```
mu_h = a0 + a1 * h ** a2
sigma_h = b0 + b1 * np.exp(b2 * h)
```

and:

```
a0 = 0.7
a1 = 0.282
a2 = 0.167
b0 = 0.07
b1 = 0.3449
b2 = -0.2073
alpha = 1.76
beta = 1.59
```

The joint PDF for h and t is then given as:

```
f_joint = f_H * f_TIH
```

My question is how can I sample random values for h and t from the joint PDF?

Comment: The ideal way to sample a random variable is with the inverse transform method, which only works if one can invert the cdf. Otherwise, one can sample using some sort of rejection sampling technique.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clear conditioning, you can generate $h$ with a `numpy.random.weibull`:
$$
h = \alpha \  \mathtt{weilbull}(\beta)
$$

and then generate $t$ from log-normal distribution `numpy.random.lognormal`:
$$
t = \mathtt{lognormal}(\mu_h, \sigma_h)
$$

As a quick check, you can generate several millions of points and check that [density plot](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/85-density-plot-with-matplotlib)  looks like a joint PDF.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement this   :)